# Remove SearchCommand in Toolbar

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to remove SearchCommand in Toolbar after add it? Below code is not working

```
Command cmd = new Command("search") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            doSomething();
        }
    };
myform.getToolbar().addSearchCommand(cmd);
myform.removeCommand(cmd);
myform.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll add a `removeSearchCommand()` API to the `Toolbar` for the next update since this is an omission.

Notice that what you are doing isn't what it seems. You are calling `addSearchCommand` but that method doesn't take a `Command` it takes an `ActionListener` so the command is treated as a listener and a new command is created to wrap that...